Why does Chigurh not wear a seatbelt (based explicitly on the textual explanation) in No Country for Old Men?
In No Country for Old Men, the description of Chigurh's traffic accident is given as:

The car that hit Chigurh in the intersection three blocks from the house was a ten year old Buick that had run a stopsign. There were no skidmarks at the site and the vehicle had made no attempt to brake. Chigurh never wore a seatbelt driving in the city because of just such hazards and although he saw the vehicle coming and threw himself to the other side of the truck the impact carried the caved-in driver side door to him instantly and broke his arm in two places and broke some ribs and cut his head and his leg.

Emphasis mine. I'm confused what the bolded line is meant to get across. Taken literally it sounds like Chigurh made a conscious effort to never wear a seatbelt because it was hazardous to his safety, so either it would have made the accident worse or it would have made the accident more likely. Neither of those statements make any sense to me. Chigurh has some extreme ideas but nothing about his demeanor or behavior shows he's superstitious about wearing protection impacting his odds of getting in an accident. He certainly enjoyed the protection of silencers on his guns and clean medical equipment during the course of the book.
I know there are arguments made about how Chigurh's outlook on life would affect how he feels about seatbelts, but I want to know what this specific line is trying to say.

He thought in event of an accident, he would be safer if he was free to move.  This, unfortunately, is a common belief, though usually in the context that you might be trapped in the car by the seat belt.
What is odd about this passage is that he had time enough to move within the truck between realizing there would be an accident and its actually occurring.

In addition to Mary's answer, it's worth remembering that Chigurh also works in a highly illegal occupation where it is in his interest to not be stuck in a static position. In the case of a crash, he wants to be able to immediately get out of the car and escape any further danger whether from attackers or the involvement of law enforcement. I don't know how common the "immobilize car by ramming and then finish off the target" is outside of films, but it is a reasonably common trope, and I know that the PIT maneuver is an accepted (if occasionally controversial) by law enforcement.
